# My programmatically created textView is not appearing

Tags: android

I am trying to create a contact management list app where when you click the add contact button, it takes you to another activity, and then when returning to the other activity a textview for the contact is created. However, when I return from the activity, my textView is not appearing above the "add contact" button. Here is my code for the Main Activity.

```
package com.example.contactmanagement;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String fname, lname, phoneNumber, email;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    protected void onResume(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        fname = bundle.getString("fname");
        lname = bundle.getString("lname");
        phoneNumber = bundle.getString("phoneNumber");
        email = bundle.getString("email");
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.contactList);


        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setLayoutParams(params);
        textView.setText(fname + lname);
        layout.addView(textView);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent("com.example.contactmanagement.addContact"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer to display text

MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Here is display activity with XML to add view dynamically

Code:

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        LinearLayout linearParentView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearParent);
        TextView dynamicTextView = new TextView(this);
        dynamicTextView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        dynamicTextView.setText(message);

        linearParentView.addView(dynamicTextView);
    }
}
```

and XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearParent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all the signature of the 'onResume' method is wrong. It does not contain the bundle parameter. 
Secondly you should be using overriding this method , (the onResume method is not meant for sending and receving results between activities).

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

}
```

to get the result from another activity. You can find more information here on how to send and result between activities.

[Getting a Result from an Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result).

At the moment you are not getting any text because your `onResume` method is never called.